# crear div que se padre de 2 de los 4 hermanos

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Llevo poco con jquery y estoy atascado en el problema que comento en el titulo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quiero crear un div con una clase que sea padre de form y del ultimo div que sale en la img.

me he quedado por aqui:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".woocommerce").append('<div class="conjunto">');   

});
```

Agradeceria la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Despues de buscar por varios otros foros, he encontrado algo muy parecido a tu problema aqui.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26301612/jquery-create-element-containing-child-element

por lo que he visto, hay varias maneras de poner crear lo que quieres. Espero que eso te ayude. Si necesita mas ayuda, no dudes en comentar.

Answer (score 0):

Para ello puedes utilizar **.wrap()**, el cual crea un elemento que envuelve alq ue tu indiques, te hice un ejemplo haciendole un padre al **form** y al **.woocommerce**:

```js
$("#crearPadre").on("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".woocommerce").wrap( "<div class='wrapper'></div>");
});

$("#crearPadre2").on("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $("form").wrap( "<div class='wrapper'></div>");
});
```

```css
.woocommerce{
 border:1px solid red;
 padding:5px;
}

form{
  border:1px solid blue;
}

.wrapper{
 border:1px solid black;
 padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="woocommerce">
  <form>
    <button id="crearPadre">Crear padre al woocommerce</button>
    <button id="crearPadre2">Crear padre al form</button>
  </form>
</div>
```